# Php capture output but also print in real time?

Tags: php, output-buffering

I want to call a callable that will output normally to stdout, but also capture its stdout in real time.

Similar to piping something thought unix `tee`; except I don't have the luxury of doing a shell call to let the shell do this for me.

This probably isn't possible but I thought I'd ask.

Is there any way to capture php's output and display it at the sane time, in relatively real time?

```
<?php

ob_start();
// ob_tee();

my_complex_spaghetti_callable();

$output = ob_get_clean();
// ...
// Do stuff without $output
```